# SPECT reconstrction using MLEM

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, iterative-method, inverse-problem

In  Single-Photon Emission Computerized Tomography (SPECT) parallel beam reconstruction using Maximum-Likelihood Expectation–Maximization(MLEM), is it sufficient to scan the object around 180 degree?  or it is required to perform full 360 scan?